getting different response than given in axios docs when I use axios.post method
This is the code snippet
try {
  const postResponse: any = await axios.post(
    url,
    messageBody,
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    }
  );
  logger.info('Response:', {postResponse: postResponse, ...logExt});
  return postResponse;
} catch(err: any){
  <catch block code here>
}

Here, I am using axios pkg's post method.
This is the response object postResponse is inside the logs:
"correlationId":"YOUR_CORRELATION_ID",
"epilogue":{"correlationId":"YOUR_CORRELATION_ID"},
"level":"info",
"message":"Response: ",
"postResponse": {
        "config": {"adapter": [
                        "xhr",
                        "http",
                        "fetch"
                    ],
                "data": "{\"data\":[SOME_DATA_HERE]",
                "env": {},
                "headers": {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, compress, deflate, br",
                "Authorization": "Bearer TOKEN_HERE",
                "Content-Length": "900",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "User-Agent": "axios/1.7.7"
            },
            "maxBodyLength": -1,
            "maxContentLength": -1,
            "method": "post",
            "timeout": 0,
            "transformRequest": [
                null
            ],
            "transformResponse": [
                null
            ],
            "transitional": {
                "clarifyTimeoutError": false,
                "forcedJSONParsing": true,
                "silentJSONParsing": true
            },
            "url": "https://exampleurl.net/environment_name",
            "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
            "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
        },
    "data": {
            "some data"
        },
    "headers": {
            "alt-svc": "h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000",
            "connection": "close",
            "content-length": "120",
            "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "date": "Tue, 08 Oct 2024 21:30:18 GMT",
            "server": "Google Frontend",
            "x-cloud-trace-context": "c261a3635d07f257822e472d5a895506;o=1"
        },
    "request": {
            "_closed": false,
            "_contentLength": "900",
            "_defaultKeepAlive": true,
            "_ended": true,
            "_events": {},
            "_eventsCount": 7,
            "_hasBody": true,
            "_header": "POST /environment_name HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nAuthorization: Bearer TOKEN_HERE\r\nUser-Agent: axios/1.7.7\r\nContent-Length: 900\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\nHost: exampleurl.net\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n",
            "_headerSent": true,
            "_keepAliveTimeout": 0,
            "_last": true,
            "_redirectable": {
                "_currentRequest": "[Circular]",
                "_currentUrl": "https://exampleurl.net/environment_name",
                "_ended": true,
                "_ending": true,
                "_events": {},
                "_eventsCount": 3,
                "_options": {
                    "agents": {},
                    "beforeRedirects": {},
                    "headers": {
                        "Accept": "application/json",
                        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, compress, deflate, br",
                        "Authorization": "Bearer TOKEN_HERE",
                        "Content-Length": "900",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "User-Agent": "axios/1.7.7"
                    },
                    "hostname": "exampleurl.net",
                    "maxBodyLength": null,
                    "maxRedirects": 21,
                    "method": "POST",
                    "nativeProtocols": {
                        "http:": {
                            "METHODS": [
                                "ACL",
                                "BIND",
                                "CHECKOUT",
                                "CONNECT",
                                "COPY",
                                "DELETE",
                                "GET",
                                "HEAD",
                                "LINK",
                                "LOCK",
                                "M-SEARCH",
                                "MERGE",
                                "MKACTIVITY",
                                "MKCALENDAR",
                                "MKCOL",
                                "MOVE",
                                "NOTIFY",
                                "OPTIONS",
                                "PATCH",
                                "POST",
                                "PROPFIND",
                                "PROPPATCH",
                                "PURGE",
                                "PUT",
                                "REBIND",
                                "REPORT",
                                "SEARCH",
                                "SOURCE",
                                "SUBSCRIBE",
                                "TRACE",
                                "UNBIND",
                                "UNLINK",
                                "UNLOCK",
                                "UNSUBSCRIBE"
                            ],
                            "STATUS_CODES": {
                                "100": "Continue",
                                "101": "Switching Protocols",
                                "102": "Processing",
                                "103": "Early Hints",
                                "200": "OK",
                                "201": "Created",
                                "202": "Accepted",
                                "203": "Non-Authoritative Information",
                                "204": "No Content",
                                "205": "Reset Content",
                                "206": "Partial Content",
                                "207": "Multi-Status",
                                "208": "Already Reported",
                                "226": "IM Used",
                                "300": "Multiple Choices",
                                "301": "Moved Permanently",
                                "302": "Found",
                                "303": "See Other",
                                "304": "Not Modified",
                                "305": "Use Proxy",
                                "307": "Temporary Redirect",
                                "308": "Permanent Redirect",
                                "400": "Bad Request",
                                "401": "Unauthorized",
                                "402": "Payment Required",
                                "403": "Forbidden",
                                "404": "Not Found",
                                "405": "Method Not Allowed",
                                "406": "Not Acceptable",
                                "407": "Proxy Authentication Required",
                                "408": "Request Timeout",
                                "409": "Conflict",
                                "410": "Gone",
                                "411": "Length Required",
                                "412": "Precondition Failed",
                                "413": "Payload Too Large",
                                "414": "URI Too Long",
                                "415": "Unsupported Media Type",
                                "416": "Range Not Satisfiable",
                                "417": "Expectation Failed",
                                "418": "I'm a Teapot",
                                "421": "Misdirected Request",
                                "422": "Unprocessable Entity",
                                "423": "Locked",
                                "424": "Failed Dependency",
                                "425": "Too Early",
                                "426": "Upgrade Required",
                                "428": "Precondition Required",
                                "429": "Too Many Requests",
                                "431": "Request Header Fields Too Large",
                                "451": "Unavailable For Legal Reasons",
                                "500": "Internal Server Error",
                                "501": "Not Implemented",
                                "502": "Bad Gateway",
                                "503": "Service Unavailable",
                                "504": "Gateway Timeout",
                                "505": "HTTP Version Not Supported",
                                "506": "Variant Also Negotiates",
                                "507": "Insufficient Storage",
                                "508": "Loop Detected",
                                "509": "Bandwidth Limit Exceeded",
                                "510": "Not Extended",
                                "511": "Network Authentication Required"
                            },
                            "globalAgent": {
                                "_events": {},
                                "_eventsCount": 2,
                                "defaultPort": 80,
                                "freeSockets": {},
                                "keepAlive": false,
                                "keepAliveMsecs": 1000,
                                "maxFreeSockets": 256,
                                "maxSockets": null,
                                "maxTotalSockets": null,
                                "options": {
                                    "noDelay": true,
                                    "path": null
                                },
                                "protocol": "http:",
                                "requests": {},
                                "scheduling": "lifo",
                                "sockets": {},
                                "totalSocketCount": 0
                            },
                            "maxHeaderSize": 16384
                        },
                        "https:": {
                            "globalAgent": {
                                "_events": {},
                                "_eventsCount": 2,
                                "_sessionCache": {
                                    "list": [
                                        "sqladmin.googleapis.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::",
                                        "login.microsoftonline.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::",
                                        "xxxxxxxx.execute-api.REGION_NAME_HERE.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::",
                                        "exampleurl.net:443:::::::::::::::::::::"
                                    ],
                                    "map": {
                                        "xxxxxxxx.execute-api.REGION_NAME_HERE.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::": {
                                            "data": [someData],
                                            "type": "Buffer"
                                        },
                                        "login.microsoftonline.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::": {
                                            "data": [someData],
                                            "type": "Buffer"
                                        },
                                        "sqladmin.googleapis.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::": {
                                            "data": [somedata],
                                            "type": "Buffer"
                                        },
                                        "exampleurl.net:443:::::::::::::::::::::": {
                                            "data": [somedata],
                                            "type": "Buffer"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "defaultPort": 443,
                                "freeSockets": {},
                                "keepAlive": false,
                                "keepAliveMsecs": 1000,
                                "maxCachedSessions": 100,
                                "maxFreeSockets": 256,
                                "maxSockets": null,
                                "maxTotalSockets": null,
                                "options": {
                                    "noDelay": true,
                                    "path": null
                                },
                                "protocol": "https:",
                                "requests": {},
                                "scheduling": "lifo",
                                "sockets": {
                                    "exampleurl.net:443:::::::::::::::::::::": [
                                        {
                                            "_SNICallback": null,
                                            "_closeAfterHandlingError": false,
                                            "_controlReleased": true,
                                            "_events": {
                                                "close": [
                                                    null,
                                                    null,
                                                    null,
                                                    null
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            "_eventsCount": 10,
                                            "_hadError": false,
                                            "_host": "exampleurl.net",
                                            "_httpMessage": "[Circular]",
                                            "_newSessionPending": false,
                                            "_parent": null,
                                            "_pendingData": null,
                                            "_pendingEncoding": "",
                                            "_readableState": {
                                                "awaitDrainWriters": null,
                                                "buffer": {
                                                    "head": null,
                                                    "length": 0,
                                                    "tail": null
                                                },
                                                "decoder": null,
                                                "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
                                                "encoding": null,
                                                "errored": null,
                                                "flowing": true,
                                                "highWaterMark": 16384,
                                                "length": 0,
                                                "pipes": [],
                                                "state": 266328
                                            },
                                            "_rejectUnauthorized": true,
                                            "_requestCert": true,
                                            "_secureEstablished": true,
                                            "_securePending": false,
                                            "_server": null,
                                            "_sockname": null,
                                            "_tlsOptions": {
                                                "isServer": false,
                                                "pipe": false,
                                                "rejectUnauthorized": true,
                                                "requestCert": true,
                                                "secureContext": {
                                                    "context": {}
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "_writableState": {
                                                "afterWriteTickInfo": null,
                                                "allBuffers": true,
                                                "allNoop": true,
                                                "autoDestroy": true,
                                                "bufferProcessing": false,
                                                "buffered": [],
                                                "bufferedIndex": 0,
                                                "closeEmitted": false,
                                                "closed": false,
                                                "constructed": true,
                                                "corked": 0,
                                                "decodeStrings": false,
                                                "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
                                                "destroyed": false,
                                                "emitClose": false,
                                                "ended": true,
                                                "ending": true,
                                                "errorEmitted": false,
                                                "errored": null,
                                                "finalCalled": true,
                                                "finished": false,
                                                "highWaterMark": 16384,
                                                "length": 0,
                                                "needDrain": false,
                                                "objectMode": false,
                                                "pendingcb": 1,
                                                "prefinished": false,
                                                "sync": false,
                                                "writecb": null,
                                                "writelen": 0,
                                                "writing": false
                                            },
                                            "allowHalfOpen": false,
                                            "alpnProtocol": false,
                                            "authorizationError": null,
                                            "authorized": true,
                                            "connecting": false,
                                            "encrypted": true,
                                            "parser": null,
                                            "secureConnecting": false,
                                            "servername": "exampleurl.net",
                                            "ssl": {
                                                "_parent": {
                                                    "onconnection": null,
                                                    "reading": true
                                                },
                                                "_parentWrap": null,
                                                "_secureContext": {
                                                    "context": {}
                                                },
                                                "reading": true
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "totalSocketCount": 1
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "/some_path",
                    "pathname": "/some_path_name",
                    "port": "",
                    "protocol": "https:"
                },
                "_redirectCount": 0,
                "_redirects": [],
                "_requestBodyBuffers": [],
                "_requestBodyLength": 900,
                "_writableState": {
                    "afterWriteTickInfo": null,
                    "allBuffers": true,
                    "allNoop": true,
                    "autoDestroy": true,
                    "bufferProcessing": false,
                    "buffered": [],
                    "bufferedIndex": 0,
                    "closeEmitted": false,
                    "closed": false,
                    "constructed": true,
                    "corked": 0,
                    "decodeStrings": true,
                    "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
                    "destroyed": false,
                    "emitClose": true,
                    "ended": false,
                    "ending": false,
                    "errorEmitted": false,
                    "errored": null,
                    "finalCalled": false,
                    "finished": false,
                    "highWaterMark": 16384,
                    "length": 0,
                    "needDrain": false,
                    "objectMode": false,
                    "pendingcb": 0,
                    "prefinished": false,
                    "sync": true,
                    "writecb": null,
                    "writelen": 0,
                    "writing": false
                }
            },
            "_removedConnection": false,
            "_removedContLen": false,
            "_removedTE": false,
            "_trailer": "",
            "aborted": false,
            "agent": {
                "_events": {},
                "_eventsCount": 2,
                "_sessionCache": {
                    "list": [
                        "sqladmin.googleapis.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::",
                        "login.microsoftonline.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::",
                        "xxxxxxxx.execute-api.REGION_NAME_HERE.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::",
                        "exampleurl.net:443:::::::::::::::::::::"
                    ],
                    "map": {
                        "xxxxxxxx.execute-api.REGION_NAME_HERE.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::": {
                            "data": [somedata],
                            "type": "Buffer"
                        },
                        "login.microsoftonline.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::": {
                            "data": [some_data],
                            "type": "Buffer"
                        },
                        "sqladmin.googleapis.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::": {
                            "data": [some_data],
                            "type": "Buffer"
                        },
                        "exampleurl.net:443:::::::::::::::::::::": {"data": [some_data]}
                        }
                }
            }
        }
}

The object received is lacking keys like status and statusText comparing it to the Response Schema given on axios documentation website, also giving some circular references.
This is the response schema as given on axios website:
{
  // `data` is the response that was provided by the server
  data: {},

  // `status` is the HTTP status code from the server response
  status: 200,

  // `statusText` is the HTTP status message from the server response
  // As of HTTP/2 status text is blank or unsupported.
  // (HTTP/2 RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.4)
  statusText: 'OK',

  // `headers` the HTTP headers that the server responded with
  // All header names are lower cased and can be accessed using the bracket notation.
  // Example: `response.headers['content-type']`
  headers: {},

  // `config` is the config that was provided to `axios` for the request
  config: {},

  // `request` is the request that generated this response
  // It is the last ClientRequest instance in node.js (in redirects)
  // and an XMLHttpRequest instance in the browser
  request: {}
}

So, my question is why the object received is lacking this two key's in object as compared to response schema?
